# Running Ubuntu from External HDD. Boots very slowly

Tags: 13.04, external-hdd

I've installed Ubuntu 13.04 on an external hard drive (usb2) and when I boot, it takes ages to get past the purple screen. Otherwise, the performance is perfectly fine. Is this just a symptom of slow r/w speeds or is there something I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The external HDD is connected via USB, correct?

If so, than, you can't expect as good performance/speed from it as you would an internal HDD, as USB can only handle so much, so fast. USB provides *very* good performance, but under heavy use (such as boot-up), it may slow down a bit.

Comment: Ok. I was looking through the boot log and there was a 15 second wait for this: `nouveau  [     DRM] 0xC605: Parsing digital output script table`. Do you know what this is?

Comment: I'm afraid not, sorry. Try googling it I guess.